# Calculate cut operation on every group in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables as:

**DT:**

```
  a |  segment
 10 | 1
 20 | 1
 30 | 1
 40 | 1
 50 | 1
 60 | 1
 70 | 1
 80 | 1
 90 | 1
100 | 1
 10 | 2
 20 | 2
 30 | 2
 40 | 2
 50 | 2
 60 | 2
 70 | 2
 80 | 2
 90 | 2
100 | 2
```

**DTBins:**

```
 bin| segmentVal
 25 | 1
 50 | 1
 75 | 1
 20 | 2
 40 | 2
 60 | 2
 80 | 2
```

I want to apply `cut` function to column 'a' of DT, grouped by column 'segment', such that resulting output is as:

Apply cut with (25, 50, 75) to all values in column a of DT, **with segment 1** and cut with (20, 40, 60, 80) to values in a, **with segment 2**.

So far I wrote:

```
DT[, bins := cut(a, breaks = DTBins[segmentVal == segment, bin]), by = seg]
```

But, this applies cut to all rows with only segment = 2.
Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
 DT[, bins := unlist(Map(function(x,y) 
      cut(x$a, breaks = y), split(DT, DT$segment), split(DTBins$bin, DTBins$segmentVal)))]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun Worked like a charm.